# Estimate mean score including missingness in R

Tags: r, mean, missing-data

I am trying to estimate a mean score based on four columns in a data frame. The condition is at least two values in a row should have non-missing values out of four values. Otherwise, if more than two NAs exist in that row, then the mean score should be NA. Let's say only three values are available in the dataset, and one NA. Then, the total score is divided by 3 because I need the sum score to be divided by the number of available values.

My data look like this:

```
a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2, NA)
b = c(2, 4, NA, 4, 1, NA, 8)
c = c(2, NA, 6, 4, NA, 4, NA)
d = c(2, 4, NA, 4, NA, 3, NA)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

> df
   a  b  c  d
1  1  2  2  2
2  1  4 NA  4
3  1 NA  6 NA
4  1  4  4  4
5 NA  1 NA NA
6  2 NA  4  3
7 NA  8 NA NA
```

I want the scores as

```
>df$mean
1.75
3
3.5
3.25
NA
3
NA
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RuiBarradas That won't quite work given the condition on when to exclude `NA`s and when not to

Comment: I agree that rowMeans() does not take care of the conditional mean estimation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do with `rowSums`,`rowMeans` and `ifelse`

```
ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df))<=2,rowMeans(df,na.rm=T),NA)
[1] 1.75 3.00 3.50 3.25   NA 3.00   NA
```